# What's the fastest way using lsof to find a single open file?

Tags: php, linux, file, lsof

I'm trying to test a single file if it is open using lsof.  Is there a faster way than this?

```
$result = exec('lsof | grep filename | wc -l');

if($result > 0) {
    //file is open
}
```

I'm thinking their must be a way to just test for one file if you know the filename.  All I really need is a true or false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a much better way.  With lsof (tested on version 4.63), you can directly query a specific file:

```
if lsof filename > /dev/null; then
    # file is open
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can skip `wc` and use the return value of grep (grep returns 0 (i.e. success) if it detects the pattern and 1 (i.e. not-success) if it does not detect the pattern):

```
if lsof | grep filename > /dev/null; then
    # filename is in output of lsof
fi
```

You can improve this a bit by using grep's `-l` flag:

```
if lsof | grep -l filename > /dev/null; then
...
```

This tells grep to stop looking once it detects it's first match.

Comment: If you actually care about the process that's using the file, better to use the `-m 1` option for grep so you actually get the matching line instead of the filename (stdin) the match was found in. (Otherwise, nice alternate use of `-l`.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't.  The answer might change by the time you try to do anything with the result.  Instead, try to do whatever you intended to do with the file and handle the "in use" error or "sharing violation".

Comment: For you: +1, from what I'm seeing I think you might be right.  Although your answer doesn't specifically answer the question.

Comment: Jared Parsons has a nice write-up on why the question itself is fundamentally flawed: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/12/10/the-file-system-is-unpredictable.aspx

In such cases, it's best not to answer the question that WAS asked, but the question that SHOULD have been asked.

Comment: -1 for a couple of reasons. Firstly, the "don't" answer is *also* naive and misguided. There are various legit reasons to want to directly query for whether files are open or advisory locks are held, like debugging, monitoring, or warning a user in advance that they may not be able to save their changes. Secondly, file pointers in Unix don't impose any kind of locking by default; unless you explicitly use `flock` or some other locking mechanism, you won't *get* any "in use" or "sharing violation" error - you'll just merrily garble your file.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Those are all worthwhile goals, but `lsof` doesn't accomplish any of them.  For debug log collection, you really need to turn to a filesystem trace.  For avoiding corruption due to simultaneous access, you need to decide whether the format is meant to be updated or rewritten.  Databases that will be updated in place *require* locking by all parties, and you simply throw away any software that accesses it without, because record locking is so fundamental.  Other formats where overwrite is appropriate should write a temporary file and then rename, which completely avoids garbling.

Comment: @MarkAmery: And your "warn user they might not be able to save their changes" is imposing Windows-centric thinking on a POSIX feature set.  In POSIX, you can rename the file and put a new one in its place even if the old file is held open.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Your link is broken, but guided me to the right place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/the-file-system-is-unpredictable

Answer (score 1):

Use `fuser`. It returns non-zero if any of the files specified are in use, and zero if they're all available.